# SAP Web IDE UI5 odata saprouter

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a SAP server with below information (must use saprouter to connect to it from afar). (3rd picture)

And i have an Odata service that i connect on LOCAL like below. (2nd picture)

Now in SAP Web IDE, i want to connect to this Odata. (1st picture)
The picture is an example to connect to Northwind Odata test server.
I need to replace the northwind odata url with my Odata url in 2nd picture.
But this url is only for local.
So how can i config this? I think it has something to do with the saprouter.
And how can i include the username and password for the Odata too?

[SAP Web IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9j9R.png)

[Odata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaAW7.png)

[SAP SERVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAw5A.png)

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you need to follow:

1. You need to expose your OData service in your NW system. I think this can be done in the /iwfnd/maint_services transaction. But Google it, because I am not a system administrator.
   Once done you should be able to access de OData inside your internal Network like this:
   `Https://host:port/sap/opu/odata...`
   Where host:port is the full qualified domain of your NW system.
2. The Cloud Platform is in the cloud (obviously), this means that it is outside your private network, so you need to configure a secure tunnel to pass your firewall. This way you can access from your SCP account to your NW in your private network.
   To configure this tunnel, SAP provides a great tool called "SAP Cloud Connector". You can download it from [here](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com)
   Google some tutorials to configure it. There are tons and it is easy.
3. Now configure a destination in the Cloud Platform cockpit. As I can see in the pictures you already did it for the Nortwind service, so I guess you know how to do it. The main difference will be that instead of pointing to Nortwind, it will point to your NW system thought the Cloud Connector.
4. Last, change the line of the manifest.json file you highlight in the first picture, so it points to the new destination.

And that's it!!